# Svn Authentication username, password and URL using Svn Kit

Tags: java, svn, authentication, svnkit

**How to do authentication of a svn url with username and password without checking out the project**

Now I am calling the **doCheckout()** method to authenticate. I don't want to download to local starge. I just want to do authentication.

My current code

```
public class SvnAuth {
    private static SVNClientManager ourClientManager;

    public boolean svnAuthentication(String svnLocation, String svnUserName,
        String svnPassword, File file) throws SVNException {

        DefaultSVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
        ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options, svnUserName,
                svnPassword);
        SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient();
        updateClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
        SVNRevision rev = SVNRevision.HEAD;
        try {
            long revision1 = updateClient.doCheckout(
                    SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(svnLocation), file, rev, rev, true);
        } catch (SVNException e) {
            SVNErrorMessage svnErrorMessage = e.getErrorMessage();
            throw new SVNException(svnErrorMessage);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

SVNKit version I am using is **1.7.4-v1**

Comment: you could use SVNLogClient instead of SVNUpdateClient

Comment: Can you please elaborate @FredericClose

Comment: Using SVNLogClient you'll use the same authentication mechanism but are not forced to check out files to validate the login/password.

Comment: You can also use SVNRepository#testConnection method.

Comment: Where is the #testConnection method in that class? @DmitryPavlenko

Comment: SVNRepository.java line 431: `public abstract void testConnection() throws SVNException;`

Comment: SVNRepository.java has only `protected` conctructor. @DmitryPavlenko

Comment: Yes, use SVNRepositoryFactory#create or ISVNRepositoryPool#createRepository

Comment: How would that satisfy my question of authenticating a user for a particular Svn Repository? @DmitryPavlenko

Comment: If testConnection fails with SVNException with a corresponding error code (SVNErrorCode), the user is not authenticated. Otherwise he/she is.

Comment: where do i set the username and password? Could you please post it as an answer. That would be really helpful. @DmitryPavlenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
private boolean checkPassword(SVNURL url, String user, String password) throws SVNException {
    SVNRepository svnRepository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url);
    try {
        svnRepository.setAuthenticationManager(new BasicAuthenticationManager(user, password));
        svnRepository.testConnection();
        return true;
    } catch (SVNException e) {
        if (e.getErrorMessage().getErrorCode() == SVNErrorCode.RA_NOT_AUTHORIZED) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    } finally {
        svnRepository.closeSession();
    }
}
```

Actually, instead of svnRepository.testConnection() you can use any method that reads some data from the repository, testConnection() is just the simplest one.

Comment: While using DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager the code execution continues even when I enter the wrong password in Windows machine.. On linux machine i get the error mentioned in this URL "http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-290"  Will your code solve that problem??